# List of SEO rules for HTML tags?

Tags: seo, css, accessibility, title-attribute

I know there are some rules related to specific attributes that some tags should have. For example, input, select and textareas should have aria-label on them. I'd like to have a full list of these rules. My goal with this is to produce a tool such as [Meyer's Diagnostic CSS Tool](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/diagnostics/index.html), but I'd like it more advanced.

Comment: The tool you want to create would be useful. There are a lot of sites producing cheat sheets, and https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#examples-of-incorrect-usage has a list of incorrect usage of tags.

Comment: Just FYI, you shouldn’t use aria-label on form elements, you should have a `<label>` element with a for= attribute pointing to the input.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a comprehensive list.  As I have discovered when coding my site that it's a moving target and everyone has their own recommendations.  And Readers are not consistent in their approach.

I think that this is a good website [ARIA Authoring Practices Guide (APG) Home](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/)

Example of Content

> **Naming with a String Attribute Via aria-label**
>
> The aria-label property enables authors to name an element with a string that is not visually rendered. For example, the name of the following button is "Close".
>
> <button type="button" aria-label="Close">X</button>
>
> The aria-label property is useful when there is no visible text content that will serve as an appropriate accessible name.
>
> The aria-label property affects assistive technology users in one of two different ways, depending on the role of the element to which it is applied. When applied to an element with one of the roles that supports naming from child content, aria-label hides descendant content from assistive technology users and replaces it with the value of aria-label. However, when applied to nearly any other type of element, assistive technologies will render both the value of aria-label and the content of the element. For example, the name of the following navigation region is "Product".

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are [SEO rules for HTML](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/valid-page-metadata) tags but what you've highlighted are aria attributes. To the best of public knowledge, these [do not have an impact on SEO](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137304/does-aria-help-seo-have-you-experienced-any-benefits-for-organic-search) and Google has stated that this form of accessibility is [**not** one of their ranking factors](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-accessibility-not-a-direct-ranking-factor/443784/).